# Clicking on an image in selenium

Tags: python

I'm having an issue clicking on an image using the Chromedriver with Selenium for the following HTML:

```
<div class="modal_buttons">
<input type="image" name="GoButton" id="GoButton" tabindex=14 title="Continue" alt="Continue" onfocus="SetLastFocus(this.id)" src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/81/83/05/240_F_81830511_aJbF2vH9yufF0UAUFQ83JDnbp0jE5mNV.jpg"
```

I tried using the following code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//div[img/@src='https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/81/83/05/240_F_81830511_aJbF2vH9yufF0UAUFQ83JDnbp0jE5mNV.jpg']").click()
```

Selenium is failing everytime, and giving the same list of errors that it can't locate the button. Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an implicit or explicit wait in Selenium for the page to load?

Comment: I believe implicit wait

Comment: Can you please show the full Python code file?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='GoButton'][@name='GoButton']").click()
```

> or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='GoButton'][@title='Continue']").click()
```

> or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='GoButton'][@title='Continue']").click()
```

> or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@src,'240_F_81830511_aJbF2vH9yufF0UAUFQ83JDnbp0jE5mNV.jpg')]")
```

Comment: I got the same error as before... it still can't locate the element

Comment: It still isn't working.... every time I'm getting the same error that "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Comment: The error says it all. Either the element is with in an `iFrame` where you have to switchTo the frame first then search for the element or you have to introduce `Explicit Wait` for the image to be clickable. Thanks